# How to fetch the result of ngxtop command in a file

Tags: nginx

I need to ferch the result of ngxtop command in a file. But when i m trying to run it from a shell script file  it goes to a running state untill I manually kill or stop it...

Answer (score 0):

I do this proccess with the next cli command group:

```
touch file.log && echo "please press CTRL+C to stop process and save ngxtop file.log" && ngxtop print request status http_referer >> file.log
```

> When you run this code will save the output in file.log the you can show the informacion with next code:

```
cat file.log
```

> This is an example when the process is complete and we load some sites in nginx while the command is executing [screeshoot of ngxtop trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqzt8.png)